# Cartesian Points on Elliptic Curves in sage

Tags: sage, elliptic-curve

I just want to sample cartesian points from an elliptic curve in $(x,y)$ form. Given one of x or y, I want to be able to calculate the other's possibilities.

Examples: I have `EllipticCurve('11a')` and I want to know where it intersects the x-axis in (x,y) coordinates. What about where the curve intersects x=5? Or where it intersects y=3?

Can somebody assist me in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to solve a polynomial equation in one variable. The `factor` function, or the `.roots` method of polynomials can do that for you.

Comment: oh, I see, that's obvious in hindsight. I got it working using `solve` easily, thank you!